# How to fix a rotting load bearing post?

Tags: wood, load-bearing, post, rot

I believe a load bearing timber post at my place is starting to rot at the bottom due to moisture. I think the post is load bearing because there is a large opening for the slide door. Does anyone know how it could be fixed? Here's a few photos of the post:

[image]

[image]

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that is not a termite lunch ? Yes it needs replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove sufficient siding to expose the beams etc that post supports.

Organise the jacks to hold up the roof / beams at that point while allowing sufficient space to work.

Replace post, consider how to make sure drainage is sufficient so the post does not sit in water etc.

You might want to get some quotes form professionals who have the equipment and experience to  do this as it is not an easy job.